# is it possible to create table in word using python and writing results into it?

Tags: python, ms-word

First of all thanks stackoverflow users. I got to know how i can write result into a file.

```
          with open('Output\\Result.doc', 'a') as fout:
                 result = str(args[0]) + " : Fail"
                 fout.write("\n")
                 fout.write(result)
```

Now, i wanted to know is it possible to create a table in word doc using python and writing result into it.?or if the table exists, how can i write result into it? first result 1 row and columns , second result 2 row and column so on.

Comment: Why are you writing to a table in a Word doc? Writing a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is practically trivial in Python, `.docx` is almost certainly harder (especially for tables), and I'm guessing `.doc` is substantially harder than that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to create the table as an html file.

Also see: [How can I create a Word document using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python), [Extracting data from HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790535/extracting-data-from-html-table)