# Converting a HTML table to a CSV in Python

Tags: python, html, csv, html-table

I am trying to convert a table in HTML to a csv in Python. The table I am trying to extract is this one:

```
<table class="tblperiode">
    <caption>Dades de per&iacute;ode</caption>
    <tr>
        <th class="sortable"><span class="tooltip" title="Per&iacute;ode (Temps Universal)">Per&iacute;ode</span><br/>TU</th>                   
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Temperatura mitjana (&deg;C)">TM</span><br/>&deg;C</th> 
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Temperatura m&agrave;xima (&deg;C)">TX</span><br/>&deg;C</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Temperatura m&iacute;nima (&deg;C)">TN</span><br/>&deg;C</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Humitat relativa mitjana (%)">HRM</span><br/>%</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Precipitaci&oacute; (mm)">PPT</span><br/>mm</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Velocitat mitjana del vent (km/h)">VVM (10 m)</span><br/>km/h</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Direcci&oacute; mitjana del vent (graus)">DVM (10 m)</span><br/>graus</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Ratxa m&agrave;xima del vent (km/h)">VVX (10 m)</span><br/>km/h</th>
            <th><span class="tooltip" title="Irradi&agrave;ncia solar global mitjana (W/m2)">RS</span><br/>W/m<sup>2</sup></th>
    </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                            00:00 - 00:30            
                </th>
                                <td>16.2</td>
                                <td>16.5</td>
                                <td>15.4</td>
                                <td>93</td>
                                <td>0.0</td>
                                <td>6.5</td>
                                <td>293</td>
                                <td>10.4</td>
                                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                            00:30 - 01:00
                </th>
                                <td>16.4</td>
                                <td>16.5</td>
                                <td>16.1</td>
                                <td>90</td>
                                <td>0.0</td>
                                <td>5.8</td>
                                <td>288</td>
                                <td>8.6</td>
                                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
```

And I want it to look something like this:

[image]

To achieve so, what I have tried is to parse the html and I have managed to build a dataframe with the data correctly doing the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
html = open("table.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.select_one("table.tblperiode")

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

 df = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)
 print(df)
```

However, I would like to have the columns name and a column indicating the interval of time, in the example of html above just two of them appear 00:00-00:30 and 00:30 1:00. Therefore my table should have two rows, one corresponding with the observations of 00:00-00:30 and another one with the observations of 00:30 and 1:00.

How could I get this information from my HTML?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917958/convert-html-into-csv

Comment: I did, but that's not working for me, I am trying now to modify that code but I couldn't get anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way of doing it, it's probably not the nicest way but it works! You can read through the comments to figure out what the code is doing!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#read the html
html = open("table.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# get the table from html
table = soup.select_one("table.tblperiode")

# find all rows
rows = table.findAll('tr')

# strip the header from rows
headers = rows[0]
header_text = []

# add the header text to array
for th in headers.findAll('th'):
    header_text.append(th.text)

# init row text array
row_text_array = []

# loop through rows and add row text to array
for row in rows[1:]:
    row_text = []
    # loop through the elements
    for row_element in row.findAll(['th', 'td']):
        # append the array with the elements inner text
        row_text.append(row_element.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
    # append the text array to the row text array
    row_text_array.append(row_text)

# output csv
with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(header_text)
    # loop through each row array
    for row_text_single in row_text_array:
        wr.writerow(row_text_single)
```

Comment: Hi. This was really helpful. I was wondering how this could be xtended to tables from multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

With this script:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = open('table.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
table = soup.select_one('table.tblperiode')
rows = []
for i, table_row in enumerate(table.findAll('tr')):
    if i > 0:
        periode = [' '.join(table_row.findAll('th')[0].text.split())]
        data = [x.text for x in table_row.findAll('td')]
        rows.append(periode + data)

header = ['Periode', 'TM', 'TX', 'TN', 'HRM', 'PPT', 'VVM', 'DVM', 'VVX', 'PM', 'RS']
with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(header)
    w.writerows(rows)
```

I've managed to generate following CSV file on output:

```
Periode,TM,TX,TN,HRM,PPT,VVM,DVM,VVX,PM,RS
00:00 - 00:30,16.2,16.5,15.4,93,0.0,6.5,293,10.4,0
00:30 - 01:00,16.4,16.5,16.1,90,0.0,5.8,288,8.6,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = open('test.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
#Specify table name which you want to read.
#Example: <table class="queryResults" border="0" cellspacing="1">
table = soup.select_one('table.queryResults')

def get_all_tables(soup):
    return soup.find_all("table")


tbls = get_all_tables(soup)
for i, tablen in enumerate(tbls, start=1):
    print(i)
    print(tablen)

def get_table_headers(table):
    headers = []
    for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th"):
        headers.append(th.text.strip())
    return headers

head = get_table_headers(table)
#print(head)

def get_table_rows(table):    
    rows = []
    for tr in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        cells = []
        # grab all td tags in this table row
        tds = tr.find_all("td")
        if len(tds) == 0:
            # if no td tags, search for th tags
            # can be found especially in wikipedia tables below the table
            ths = tr.find_all("th")
            for th in ths:
                cells.append(th.text.strip())
        else:
            # use regular td tags
            for td in tds:
                cells.append(td.text.strip())
        rows.append(cells)
    return rows

table_rows = get_table_rows(table)
#print(table_rows)

def save_as_csv(table_name, headers, rows):
    pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers).to_csv(f"{table_name}.csv")

save_as_csv("Test_table", head, table_rows)
```