# Parsing HTML tr returns empty list

Tags: python, html, xml

I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790535/extracting-data-from-html-table) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325216/parse-html-table-to-python-list) in order to parse a table from Wikipedia.

Specifically, I'd like to just get all the rows, and within each row, dump the contents of each column.

My code uses the `xml` library under MacOS X, but all I get is an **empty list of rows**.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

s = open("wikiactors20century.txt", "r").read()

# tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(s)
# rows = tree.findall()
# headrow = rows[0]
# datarows = rows[1:]
#
# for num, h in enumerate(headrow):
#     data = ", ".join([row[num].text for row in datarows])
#     print "{0:<16}: {1}".format(h.text, data)

table = xml.etree.ElementTree.XML(s)
rows = iter(table)
headers = [col.text for col in next(rows)]
for row in rows:
    values = [col.text for col in row]
    print dict(zip(headers, values))
```

The input file [has been pasted here in PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/PQAbD9U5). Both `xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring` and `xml.etree.ElementTree.XML` versions cannot retrieve the row list. However, if I make a dummy table as this

```
s = "<table>  <tr><td>a</td><td>1</td></tr>  <tr><td>b</td><td>2</td></tr>  <tr><td>c</td><td>3</td></tr>  </table>"
```

then parsing works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some cleaning I must apply before parsing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try does not have the same structure like wikipedia example has.

```
>>> list(table)
[<Element 'thead' at 0x7ff0fdb73f50>, <Element 'tbody' at 0x7ff0fdb78590>, <Element 'tfoot' at 0x7ff0fb995a90>]
```

You can get headers name with:

```
>>> columns = list(k.text for k in table[0][0])
```

And then iter every rows to build data table:

```
>>> data_table = list(dict(zip(columns, list(v.text for v in row))) for row in table[1])
>>> print(json.dumps(data_table, indent=2))
[
  {
    "L,S": "L", 
    "Cause of death": "~", 
    "null": "F", 
    "Noms": "1", 
    "Wins": "0", 
    "Age": "26", 
    "Actor": null, 
    "Born": "1990", 
    "Film": null, 
    "Last": "~", 
    "WoF": "~", 
    "Died": "~", 
    "First": "2001"
  }, 
  {
    "L,S": "1L,1S", 
    "Cause of death": "~", 
    "null": "M", 
    "Noms": "2", 
    "Wins": "0", 
    "Age": "39", 
    "Actor": null, 
    "Born": "1977", 
    "Film": null, 
    "Last": "~", 
    "WoF": "~", 
    "Died": "~", 
    "First": "2001"
  }, 

[...]
```

*Note: There is some parsing issues with links, and inner tags. It can be solved with `itertext` or deeper parsing.*