# 'NoneType' error due to change in HTML. Q. How do you help changing data formats?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error on the below HTML that gives me an error (missing data between ).
I only want to **scrape** the data after strong tag, so GOOD, 1:56:5 and 1:56.5

```
<td><strong>Track Rating:</strong> GOOD</td>
<td></td>
<td><strong>Gross Time:</strong> 1:56:5</td>
<td><strong>Mile Rate:</strong> 1:56:5</td>
```

HTML that works fine (no missing data)

```
<td><strong>Track Rating:</strong> GOOD</td>
<td><strong>Gross Time:</strong> 2:29:6</td>
<td><strong>Mile Rate:</strong> 1:58:6</td>
<td><strong>Lead Time:</strong> 30.3</td>
```

My code to **scrape** this data is

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import requests
import re
import csv
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = "http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate="
base1_url = "http://www.harness.org.au"

webpage_response = requests.get('http://www.harness.org.au/racing/results/?firstDate=')

soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")

format = "%d-%m-%y"
delta = timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)


enddate = datetime(2019, 1, 1)



while enddate <= yesterday:
    enddate += timedelta(days=1)
    enddate1 = enddate.strftime("%d-%m-%y") 
    new_url = base_url + str(enddate1)
    soup12 = requests.get(new_url)
    soup1 = bs(soup12.content, "html.parser") 
    table1 = soup1.find('table', class_='meetingListFull')
    
    tr = table1.find_all('tr', {'class':['odd', 'even']})
    
    for tr1 in tr or trr:
        tr2 = tr1.find('a').get_text()
        tr3 = tr1.find('a')['href']
        newurl = base1_url + tr3
        with requests.Session() as s:
            webpage_response = s.get(newurl)
            soup = bs(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
            #soup1 = soup.select('.content')
            results = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'forPrint'})
....
for race in results:
tableoftimes = race.find('table', class_='raceTimes')
trackrating = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").findPrevious('td').contents[1]
grosstime = tableoftimes.find(text="Track Rating:").find_next('td').contents[1]
milerate = tableoftimes.find(text="Gross Time:").findNext('td').contents[1]
leadtime = tableoftimes.find(text="Mile Rate:").findNext('td').contents[1]
firstquarter = tableoftimes.find(text="Lead Time:").findNext('td').contents[1]
....
```

Where the dots are im just appending to list to utilise data

My Goal - later append to list to have all data. Best case is i want to grab data even if complete, but im completely stuck where i'd even create a rule to just ignore all data if incomplete. Tried a few things like next neighbour but i constantly get an error saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext' due to the data changing in website.

***Update***
I have updated code to

```
tableoftimes = race.find('table', class_='raceTimes')
                for row in tableoftimes.find_all('tr'):
                    string23 = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all('td')]
```

Which prints
['Track Rating: *GOOD*', 'Gross Time: *2:05:1*', 'Mile Rate: *1:56:4*', 'Lead Time:  *8.1*']
['First Quarter: *29.4*', 'Second Quarter: *32*', 'Third Quarter: *28.4*', 'Fourth Quarter: *27.2*']
['Margins: HFHD x HFNK']

I want the data in italics, but only if it meets header. Most if statements i try give me the error - 'list' object has no attribute 'string' or something similar as i'm trying to reach text in a nested list. Any ideas from here?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some None-safety with a couple of nested ifs, but it would get really messy if you had to add if for each find that can potentially return None. Try this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791040/9392216

```
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    datarow = [td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")]
```

Comment: yea so even if i did nested ifs, the link you've sent presumes headings align with data where the html i want doesnt seem to...

Comment: Can you share bigger context of the html file you're working with? So I could reproduce?

Comment: can i send it to you? sorry unfamilar with stackoverflow and its much bigger than the character allowance?

Comment: I think the approach with `find_all("tr")` and `find_all("td")` will do fine with empty `td` tags

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<table class="meetingListFull">
<td><strong>Track Rating:</strong> GOOD</td>
<td><strong>Gross Time:</strong> 2:29:6</td>
<td><strong>Mile Rate:</strong> 1:58:6</td>
<td><strong>Lead Time:</strong> 30.3</td>
</table>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table1 = doc.select('table.meetingListFull')
strongs = table1.selects('strong')
print([(s.text,s.nextText()) for s in strongs])
```

Result:

```
[('Track Rating:', 'GOOD'), ('Gross Time:', '2:29:6'), ('Mile Rate:', '1:58:6'), ('Lead Time:', '30.3')]
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: this wouldnt help with the missing data - s.nexttext wouldnt return whats needed in this instance?

Comment: @BradLangtry I use strong, not TD. You should run the code to see the result.

Comment: When i run this i get TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```
doc = SimplifiedDoc(tableoftimes)
                table123 = doc.select('table.meetingListFull')
                strongs = table123.selects('strong')
                print([(s.text, s.nextText()) for s in strongs])
```
@dabingsou

Comment: @BradLangtry It should be caused by the parameter tableoftimes. the SimplifiedDoc method receives a string.