# Loop in web Table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new using python and I am trying to get some values from a table in a webpage, I need to get the values in yellow from the web page:

[image]

I have this code, it is getting all the values in the "Instruments" column but I don't know how to get the specific values:

```
body = soup.find_all("tr")
for Rows in body:
        RowValue = Rows.find_all('th')
        if len(RowValue) > 0:
            CellValue = RowValue[0]     
            ThisWeekValues.append(CellValue.text)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: where's the link/HTML?

Comment: https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/

Comment: `pd.read_html('https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h15/')` in case you are familiar with pandas. Have a look at [Extracting data from HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11790535/7259176) and [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')

if 'Your element id`  in ids:
    Do something
```

One of the ways could be this, since only `id` is different.

Comment: the problem is that 6 month exists in treasury bills and treasury constant section-i need the 6 month in constant

Comment: That just leaves `id` then..I guess. Probably searching by the list of `ids` then.